# Copyright disclaimer as a footnote at bottom of first page

Tags: footnotes, typography

I am writing a scientific paper and I am having difficulty adding a "copyright" footer on the first page. I am currently having a paper which looks like this (from [howtotex.com](http://www.howtotex.com)):

[image]

([Link to template](http://www.howtotex.com/download/2col-journalpaper-howtotex.tex))

I altered it a little bit, so far no problems. However I want to have a little text above the "1template by howtotex.com" which is needed for the journal I am writing for. In this text information like where it was presented and a copyright disclaimer is added. So in between the black line and the "1template from howtotex.com" and without a number in front of it. I have no clue how to do that, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: "(...) is needed for the journal I am writing for"
Doesn't the journal provide a mandatory class, including command definitions for this kind of things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing it in the `article` class (which is used in the template you link to) is by inserting the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycopyright#1{%
    \protected@xdef \@thanks {\@thanks \protect \footnotetext [\the \c@footnote ]{#1}}%
    \protected@xdef \@bs@thanks {\@bs@thanks \protect \footnotetext [\the \c@footnote ]{#1}}
}
\makeatother
```

and then calling the newly defined `\mycopyright{...}` command just before `\thanks{...}`, like so

```
\textsc{Jonathan S. Doe}\mycopyright{Copyright: my mum}%
\thanks{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{howtoTeX.com}}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the internals of \thanks have been redefined in the past ten years. I get `\bs@thanks` is an undefined control sequence when I try this

Answer (score 0):

Myself, I often use the `sigplanconf` class file, which comes with a built-in copyright notice that you can customise yourself. Saves you making it yourself! Download it [here](http://www.sigplan.org/authorinformation.htm).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the OP's problem. Can you show how to get the desired output in the `article` class, perhaps by reusing a command defined in the `sigplanconf` class?