# How to place a copyright note at the bottom of a page after the footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, typography

Similarly to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112329/copyright-disclaimer-as-a-footnote-at-bottom-of-first-page) question I need to put a copyright note on the first page of a paper. I would like to have a similar `\mycopyright` command to set its text. However, differently from the other question, I would like the copyright note to appear *after* any other footnote of the page coming from the paper.

This is a starting point:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Mr Someone\\University of Somewhere}

\newcommand\copyrightnote[1]{}

\copyrightnote{Copyright notice}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \lipsum[1]\footnote{Some footnote}
  \lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is in the page footer an option, or should it be below the footnotes and above the footer, with a footnote sep-rule even if there wasn't any footnote? And is it safe to assume that the first page is always the right one, even if the title takes up the whole page?

Comment: It should be typeset as a kind of footnote without marker, but after any other footnotes of the page. In the footer I have the page number. I’ll clarify the question! Yes: always on the first page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The following patches parts of LaTeX's output routine and is not thoroughly tested, use with caution.*

The following defines the macro `\copyrightnote`, it places its argument below the footnotes. The formatting is copied from LaTeX's standard definition of `\@footnotetext`. You should call it either in your preamble or after `\begin{document}` (just make sure it is before the first page was shipped out if you use it). The patching of the output routine is only done if you really use `\copyrightnote`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Mr Someone\\University of Somewhere}

\makeatletter
\newinsert\copyrightnote@ins
\count\copyrightnote@ins=1000
\dimen\copyrightnote@ins=8in
\newcommand*\copyrightnote@hook
  {%
    % place 
    \unvbox\copyrightnote@ins
    \global\let\@makecol\copyrightnote@makecol
  }
\let\copyrightnote@AtBeginDocument\AtBeginDocument
\AtBeginDocument{\let\copyrightnote@AtBeginDocument\@firstofone}
\newcommand*\copyrightnote@firstuse
  {%
    \gdef\copyrightnote@firstuse
      {\global\skip\copyrightnote@ins=\bigskipamount\gdef\copyrightnote@firstuse{}}%
    % backup to later restore it
    \global\let\copyrightnote@makecol\@makecol
    % after the actual footnotes are placed we place something else
    \xpatchcmd\@makecol{\unvbox\footins}{\unvbox\footins\copyrightnote@hook}
      {}{\GenericError{}{patching @makecol failed}{}{}}
    \copyrightnote@AtBeginDocument
      {%
        % trick the output routine to think there are footnotes, even if there
        % are none
        \ifvoid\footins
          \insert\footins{}% 
        \else
          \global\skip\copyrightnote@ins=\bigskipamount
        \fi
      }%
  }
\newcommand\copyrightnote[1]
  {%
    \copyrightnote@firstuse
    \copyrightnote@AtBeginDocument
      {%
        \insert\copyrightnote@ins
          {%
            \reset@font\footnotesize
            \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
            \splittopskip\footnotesep
            \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox
            \floatingpenalty\@MM
            \hsize\columnwidth
            \@parboxrestore
            \color@begingroup
            \parindent1em
            \noindent
            \hskip1.8em
            \ignorespaces #1\@finalstrut\strutbox
            \color@endgroup
          }%
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\copyrightnote{Copyright notice}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]\footnote{Some footnote}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

With a footnote:

[image]

Without a footnote:

[image]

Comment: That seems to do what I need, but the complexity is a little bit scaring. Isn't there any package that helps with this kind of things?

Comment: @gigabytes none that I'm aware of (but I don't know that many packages), maybe one could built something by patching the `footmisc` package, I don't know, but that would just change the things to patch, not the potential complexity. The only hard part is in `\copyrightnote@firstuse` all the stuff in `\copyrightnote` is just copy+pasted from `\@footnotetext` to get similar formatting.

Comment: I see. Isn’t there a way to copy or use \@footnotetext itself instead of copy/pasting? What did you changed wrt the original definition? Maybe we can shorten the code by using some etoolbox patching.

Comment: @gigabytes I've changed the `\insert\footins`, removed the labelling mechanism related stuff, extracted parts of the definition of `\@makefntext` and removed the footnote mark from what I've extracted. Patching doesn't seem worth it imho.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package [textpos](https://ctan.org/textpos), and define your copyright notice macro to insert a text block wherever you like. I use a similar command to place the company logos in my memos etc. Our company layout style requires that the logo is at an exact position, but since I always use A4 paper, it is easy.

My macro fix the text position relative to the absolute start of the page (0,0), so the copyright will end up at the exact place, whatever is written on the page.

If you need it differently, you can positioning the note relative to a paragraph, and you can calculate the position using [calc](https://ctan.org/calc) syntax.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\copyrightnote}[1]{%
  \begin{textblock}{100}(35,280)
      \textbf{#1}%
  \end{textblock}%
    }

\title{Copyright under footnotes}
\author{Mr Someone\\University of Somewhere}


\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\copyrightnote{This text is copyrighted Mr. Someone}
  \lipsum[1]\footnote{Some footnote}
  \lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Theis is not exactly what I needed, because the notice is not displayed as a footnote.

Comment: @gigabytes No, but you can place it and format it as a footnote, and you can also place it relative to any footnote on the page. If you requirements are so strict that the note has to be a footnote (note only formatted as a footnote) and it has to be place after other footnote on page one, then you need a solution that test if there are any other footnotes on page one. Then you have skillmon's solution, which is complicated, but works.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you need but too long for a comment/suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{2em})%
    {\makebox[0pt][c]{%
      \small\bfseries\color{red}\copyright Here is my copyright note!
      }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be a start, but then I need to position the picture in the same position as a footnote and ensure nothing gets printed on top of it from the normal test flow